# Retrieve parent and child in a tree architecture

Tags: database-design, tree

I have modelized a parent-child relation in a database using a nested set architecture.

Every child(leaves) are linked to a table containing opening dates, but the parents are not.

I would like to be able to retrieve all the leaves opened at a certain time, and their parents if all the child of that parent are opened.

Is there anyway to do this fast ? I imagine something like making a sub-request, but this is nor pretty, nor fast; the best would be to do it in just one query.

May I change my nested set architecture to another one in order to make it easier to build this request ?

**Edit:**

I'm using MySql, but I can change to any other database if this is mandatory to achieve my goal.

This is what my node ( parent-child ) table looks like:

```
id (int)
lft (int)
rgt (int)
root_id (int , self reference to the root id, used to generate multi-rooted tree)
level (int)

name (string)
description (string)
...
```

My opening_dates table looks like:

```
id (int)
node_id (int)
start (datetime)
end (datetime)
status (bool, 0 for an opened date, 1 for a close one)
```

I also add that my parent-child won't be changed often, that is why I decided to go for a nested set architecture.
My aim here is to be as fast as possible when "select querying" the system.

Comment: Can you show us your table structures? And which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle?

Comment: Some questions: I assume there is a relationship between your node table and the `opening_dates` table? What is the `root_id` field used for in the node table? What is the `status` boolean field used for in the `opening_dates` table?

Comment: I have no experience with nested sets, but it would be quite easy to solve with an adjancacy model (using a "parent_id" column) and a DBMS that supports recursive queries (e.g. PostgreSQL, Oracle and many others).

Comment: My node table is linked to opening_dates via a node_id foreign key. The status column contains 0 for an opened date, 1 for a close one. Maybe it would be "quite easy" using adjency model, but would require to select the leaves opened, then to select recursively all the parents having all their child opened. This seems quite clunky to me, but maybe there is no other option here.

Comment: I'm going off the topic of you question but there is no need for the `status` field in the `opening_dates` table. Use `NULL` in the dates fields where `start = NULL`: site not open yet; `start <> NULL AND end = NULL`: site open; `end <> NULL`: site closed. Then there is no need to keep the status field up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Af far as I know, MySQL doesn't support hierarchical queries. It's very simple to do using Oracle but in case of MySQL you might need to create stored function for such a purpose.
Try to read [this howto create hierarchical query in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

Comment: Most probably that's why the OP uses a nested set model which does not required hierarchical queries

Comment: That is exactly why i used a nested set, plus the fact that i'm not keen on hierarchical queries.